# Schwarz Inequality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, vectors, notation

The book—*Principles of Quantum Mechanics* by R.Shankar—proves the inequality in a way that leaves me unsettled. The proof is given in [page 17](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.fisica.net/mecanica-quantica/Shankar%2520-%2520Principles%2520of%2520quantum%2520mechanics.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi4x82m8_jaAhWIr48KHaL2BBMQFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3t59bGXXAPQE5joxcE1CKZ). The author intends to compute $$\langle Z|Z \rangle =\langle V - \frac{{ \langle W|V \rangle}}{|W|^2} W|V-\frac{{\langle W|V \rangle}}{|W|^2}W\rangle$$

Firstly, shouldn't $\langle Z|$ be equal to $\langle V| - \frac{{\langle W|V \rangle}^*}{|W|^2}  \langle W|$?

Considering  $\langle Z| =\langle V| - \frac{{\langle W|V \rangle}^*}{|W|^2} \langle W|$ to compute $\langle Z|Z \rangle =\langle V - \frac{{ \langle W|V \rangle}^*}{|W|^2} W|V-\frac{{\langle W|V \rangle}}{|W|^2}W\rangle$ I get, $$\langle Z|Z \rangle = \langle V-\frac{{\langle W|V\rangle}^*}{|W|^2}W|V\rangle -\langle V-\frac{{\langle W|V\rangle}^*}{|W|^2}W|\frac{{\langle W|V\rangle}}{|W|^2}W\rangle$$

$$=(\langle V|V-\frac{{\langle W|V\rangle}^*}{|W|^2}W\rangle)^*-(\langle W \frac{{\langle W|V\rangle}}{|W|^2}|V-\frac{{\langle W|V\rangle}^*}{|W|^2}W\rangle)^*$$

$$=\langle V|V \rangle - \frac{\langle V|W \rangle\langle V|W \rangle}{|W|^2}-\frac{\langle W|V \rangle\langle W|V \rangle}{|W|^2}+\frac{\langle W|V \rangle\langle V|W \rangle}{|W|^2}$$

I get stuck here. If I, however, start with $\langle Z|Z \rangle =\langle V - \frac{{ \langle W|V \rangle}}{|W|^2} W|V-\frac{{\langle W|V \rangle}}{|W|^2}W\rangle$ I get,

$$\langle Z|Z\rangle =(\langle V|V-\frac{{\langle W|V\rangle}}{|W|^2}W\rangle)^*-(\langle W \frac{{\langle W|V\rangle}}{|W|^2}|V-\frac{{\langle W|V\rangle}}{|W|^2}W\rangle)^*$$

$$= \langle V|V \rangle - \frac{\langle V|W \rangle\langle W|V \rangle}{|W|^2}-\frac{\langle V|W \rangle\langle V|W \rangle}{|W|^2}+\frac{\langle V|W \rangle\langle V|W \rangle}{|W|^2} = \langle V|V \rangle - \frac{\langle V|W \rangle\langle W|V \rangle}{|W|^2}$$

Exactly what the result is. But I notice that what is there in the book is not what I have obtained in the step preceding the final result. Where am I falling out of track?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I will edit it now. Sigh!

Comment: Hint for the first question: recall that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is sesquilinear, $\langle \lambda v,u\rangle=\lambda^*\langle v,u\rangle$.

Comment: Shankar is fine, *but* I see in your linked copy you have done violence to the crucial (1.3.9) : you seem to have trouble  conjugating a complex number past the state demarcator |  .

Comment: @CosmasZachos It would be really helpful if you could tell me what exactly is going wrong. I have edited the post.

Comment: @J.Murray I have obeyed it, have I not?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I do not understand the contents of your comment yet. I have never taken linear algebra; Shankar introduces me to it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If we define
$$|A + \lambda B\rangle = |A\rangle + \lambda |B\rangle$$
then it follows that
$$\langle A + \lambda B| \equiv \big[|A + \lambda B\rangle\big]^\dagger = \big[|A\rangle + \lambda |B\rangle\big]^\dagger =  \langle A | + \lambda^*\langle B |$$

This is a minor subtlety of bra-ket notation, but it seems to be the source of your confusion.  More explicitly,

$$\big[|A + \lambda B\rangle\big]^\dagger \neq \langle A + \lambda^* B|$$

The conjugation only comes into play if you "break up" the bra.

Comment: In addition to this, I violated the axiom of linearity in ket. I get it now!

Comment: One doubt regarding the notation here. $\langle V|$ tells us that we need to take the transpose conjugate of $|V\rangle$( column vector of elements ), right?

Comment: @R004 yes, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

You might delete the question after you appreciate the point.
By your own rule,
$$ |Z \rangle = |V\rangle-\frac{{\langle W|V \rangle}}{|W|^2}|W\rangle, \\ 
 \langle Z| =\langle V| - \frac{{\langle V|W \rangle} }{|W|^2}  \langle W| \qquad \Longrightarrow\\
\langle Z|Z\rangle=\langle V|V \rangle - \frac{\langle V|W \rangle\langle W|V \rangle}{|W|^2}~,
$$
where the 2nd and 3rd term in the product reverse the sign of the 4th term.

Comment: I violated the axiom of linearity in ket. That's the reason behind me falling out of track. I get it now.